# Retrieving Sharepoint List C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to retrieve a SharePoint list and all the items within it, however I CANNOT seem to grab the list. I can connect to the site fine, but when I try to retrieve the list, I get a "CollectionNotInitialized" error. I'm logged in as admin and have full control permissions. Can anyone help explain this issue to me? Here is my code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        try
        { 
            string userName = "//my user name";
            string password = "//my password";
            SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString();

            foreach(char c in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                ssPwd.AppendChar(c);
            }

            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://my fake site.com");
            SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, ssPwd);
            context.Credentials = credentials;


            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web.Lists);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Accounts");
            context.Load(list);

            context.ExecuteQuery();



        }
        catch
        {
           // Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: sharepoint 2013 online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
    var lists = web.Lists;
    context.Load(lists, all => all
      .Where(l => l.RootFolder.Name == "Accounts")
      .Include(l => l.Id));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    list = lists.Single();
```