# How to retrive sharepoint list data in c#.net project

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sharepoint, bots

I want to retrive sharepoint list data in c#.net project. Please suggest me step by step procedure.

Comment: Step 1, google what you want. Step 2 provide the code here you came up with that's not working.

Comment: I have created  bot using bot framework template , i want  to retrive sharepoint list data in c#.net project

Comment: StackOverflow is not code generation service. You will have to provide code you need help with here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115675/retrieving-sharepoint-list-c-sharp have you looked at this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving Sharepoint List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115675/retrieving-sharepoint-list-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples about GRUD on SharePoint list, please take a reference:
[SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/)

Thanks
Baker Kong